# React shows the answer options the first time, and then when I reload I get an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm currently trying to make an quiz in React app and this is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'





// Here is the function that gets new questions from an API

function App(){
  const [allQuestions, setAllQuestions] = useState([])
  const [currQuestion, setCurrQuestion] = useState(0)
  
  function newQuiz() { 
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=12&difficulty=easy&type=multiple')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => 
      setAllQuestions(data.results.map((item) => {
      return{
        id: nanoid(),
        question: item.question,
        correctAnswer: item.correct_answer,
        allAnswers: [...item.incorrect_answers, item.correct_answer]
        
      }

    })))

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    newQuiz();

  }, [])
  

  return(
    <div>
      // here, I render the answer options to the screen
      {allQuestions[currQuestion].allAnswers.map(quest => <button>{quest}</button> )}
       
    </div>
  )
  
 
  
}

export default App
```

So, after I save, everything works just fine, and after I reload I get this error in console:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log(data)` in your api call and see? result there or not

Answer (score 1):

You must add safe checks before trying to read something from array, because list will be empty until you resolve data inside useEffect, and when trying to read on an element of empty list, you will end up with error like that one. Add checks using `?` (or add ternary check with `allQuestions.length > 0`), like this:

```
{allQuestions[currQuestion]?.allAnswers?.map(quest => <button>{quest}</button> )}
```